# advice on how to design an extendable backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have the following backbone application.

It's a generic crud view, with the following template:

```
<div id="<%= crudId %>">
  <div class="header-view"></div>
  <div class="table-view"></div>
  <div class="form-view"></div>
</div>
```

You can see the crud live here: http://bbbootstrap.com.ar/index.html#Wine

The view itself has subviews, to be rendered in the table-view and the form-view.

The thing is I want it to be a base crud view, and to be easily entendable, adding new subviews, for example, adding a new panel to issue some bulk operations.

These are the possible solutions I came out with so far

1- inheritance: create a new CrudBulkView inheriting from CrudView, modify the template to have a bulk-view place holder.

pro: inheritance can provide quite an elegant and simple solution
cons: it's a bit limiting, I'd like to just be able to compose the BulkView and add it to the CrudView.

2- add a method to crudview like addView(view, place) with place being something like 'beforeForm', 'afterForm', 'beforeTable', etc... (it's much too hardcoded...

cons: too hardcoded

3- pass a function with each subview I want to add, that takes care of creating the dom and attaching to it, right after CrudView has rendered the container. the method could be called setEl and return the newly created el.

pro: really flexible
cons: adds some complexity to the process of attaching the subview to the dom

4-modify the crudView template and then attach to it, something like this:

```
<div id="<%= crudId %>">
  <div class="header-view"></div>
  <div class="table-view"></div>
  <div class="form-view"></div>
  <div class="bulk-view"></div
</div>
```

then bulkView.el would be '.bulk-view'

pro: simple approach
cons: have to mess around with strings, instead of dealing with the dom

I think it's not so strange what I'm trying to achieve. I just want to add a view to a container view, being as much decoupled as possible, and being able to establish where it should be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your response to my previous answer I went through and modified my example to hopefully give you an idea of how you can implement a system with named views that allows you to control the ordering as you desire. Let me know if this helps or if you have any questions about how it works.

```
var viewCtor = Backbone.View.prototype.constructor;

// Assuming we have a reference to the subviews already
var BaseCrudView = Backbone.View.extend({
  // This is null for an important reason, see comment in constructor
  subViews: null,

  // Override the constructor instead of initialize since this is meant to be a base object, so things that
  // inherit don't have to remember to call the parent inialize every time.
  constructor: function() {
    viewCtor.apply(this, arguments);

    // It is important this is initialized when instantiating the view rather than in the prototype.
    // Backbone's extend() will "copy" the prototype properties of the parent when extending, which really
    // just performs an assignment. If this were initialized above in the prototype then all children
    // that inherit from that prototype would share the exact same instance of the array/object. If a child
    // adds something to the array, it would be changed for all instances that inherit from the parent.
    this.subViews = {
      header: new HeaderView(),
      table: new TableView
    };

    this.subViewOrder = [
      'header',
      'table'
    ];
  },

  addBefore: function(subView, name, beforeView) {
    this.subViews[name] = subView;
    var viewLoc = this.subViewOrder.indexOf(beforeView);
    if(viewLoc == -1) {
      viewLoc = 0;
    }
    this.subViewOrder.splice(viewLoc, 0, name);
  },

  addAfter: function(subView, name, afterView) {
    this.subViews[name] = subView;
    var viewLoc = this.subViewOrder.indexOf(afterView);
    if(viewLoc == -1) {
      viewLoc = this.subViewOrder.length - 1;
    }
    this.subViewOrder.splice(viewLoc + 1, 0, name);
  },

  moveBefore: function(name, beforeView) {
    this.addBefore(this.subViews[name], name, this.subViewOrder.splice(this.subViewOrder.indexOf(name), 1));
  },

  moveAfter: function(name, afterView) {
    this.addAfter(this.subViews[name], name, this.subViewOrder.splice(this.subViewOrder.indexOf(name), 1));
  },

  render: function() {
    var that = this;

    _.each(this.subViewOrder, function(viewName) {
      // Assumes the render() call on any given view returns 'this' to get 'el'
      that.$el.append(this.subViews[viewName].render().el);
    });

    return this;
  }
});

var BulkCrudView = BaseCrudView.extend({
  inialize: function() {
    // Skipping the last parameter causes it to insert at the end
    this.addAfter(new BulkView(), 'bulkView');
  }
});
```

With this you could easily extend the `BulkCrudView` and modify its `subViews` array in initialize to add/insert whatever you want. Though, it'd work just as well to instantiate a `BaseCrudView` and work with the view methods. Just whatever feels cleaner and/or floats your boat.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the example I gave I'm just appending each subview one after the other. But I'd like it to be more flexible. Let's say I want to add a subview above the header, or after the header and before the table body, or at the end, etc... I would need some kind of template just to specify where I want each subview to be inserted.

Comment: You could use a object with named keys referencing the views and then an array specifying the order, which you could modify as you desire in each view that inherits from it. Would that achieve more what you're looking for? I can modify my answer to demonstrate if that would help.

Comment: I just modified my answer, let me know what you think.